# jQuery Mobile - listview() with data-filter="true" and ajax content

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile

This is my html:

```
<ul data-role="list-view" data-filter="true"></ul>
```

My JS loads the ul with data and then I call listview().

```
$('#page').live('pagebeforecreate', function(){
        // My Ajax code
    });
    $('#page').live("pageinit", function(){
        $('#page ul').listview();
    });
```

That works except the search bar at the top doesn't appear.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
data-role="list-view"
```

When the right way is

```
data-role="listview"
```

that is why the search bar at the top doesn't appear.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling `$('#page').live("pageinit", function(){
            $('#page ul').listview();
        });`

Do the following:

```
  $('#page').live("pageinit", function(){
    init();
    });


<ul id="mylist" data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-filter="true" >

</ul>

function init()
{
    type: "GET",
   $.ajax({
     url: "BirthdayInvitations.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function ParseXml(xml)
    {
         $(xml).find("event").each(function() {  
     $("#mylist").append('<li><a href="' + "#" + '">' +this.textContent + '</a></li>');
     }); 
     $("#mylist").listview('refresh');   
     }}); 

   }

This is working i tried it out and i am using in my application.
```

Comment: This did not work for me.  I got this error in firebug:
uncaught exception: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `$('#page ul').listview('refresh');` instead of just `$('#page ul').listview();`. You need to refresh a jQuery-Mobile component when you update it via Ajax.

Comment: If I do that, then I get this error in firebug: uncaught exception: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Comment: You wrote `data-role="list-view"` instead of `data-role="listview"`. May it have something to do with it?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to call:

```
$('#page ul').listview('create');
```

after you are done populating your list with jscript.

To refresh it's content (only after it's creation), you could call:

```
$('#page ul').listview('refresh');
```

see [jqm documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc3/docs/pages/page-scripting.html)