# JQuery Mobile listview lose search filter functionality after ajax call

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a list like this

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="list" data-filter="true"></ul>
```

it looks good on startup and get a nice (working filter/search-bar).

But then I add some rows (li) to the list with an ajax call.

```
 $('#list').append('<li>item</li>');
```

Then I reload the list to get it to rerender the list with the nice JQM UI.

```
$("#list").listview();
```

My problem is that after this the filter/searchbar stops working.
(It is stil displayed but it is not filtering).

I have tried to add the whole list in the callback (putting a  in the html and then readding the whole list (append('

Any suggestions on how to hook the search function back on again?

Comment: I believe in jQuery mobile you have to re-parse the elements again.  It's something like 

`$("#list").trigger("create");`

Comment: Try this: `$("#list").listview("refresh");`. Worked for me.

Comment: When I reparse the list with refresh I get the following error: "uncaught exception: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'."
When I reparse it with $("#list").listview(); instead it works in all other aspects than the search (the JQM UI is added and so on).

Comment: I have also tried the trigger create but it does not seem to help (doesn't cast any errors thought, but the problem with the search persists).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution here: [jQuery Mobile - listview() with data-filter="true" and ajax content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306645/jquery-mobile-listview-with-data-filter-true-and-ajax-content)

First of all I had for some reason data-role="list-view" instead of data-role="listview".

The second thing I changed was that I removed the document.ready() method and replaced it with two methods:

```
$(document).live( 'pagebeforecreate',function(event){
    // append stuff to UL
});
$(document).live("pageinit", function(){
    $('#list').listview();
});
```